# Thread Safe e sua ligação com Collections

Tags: c#, java, estrutura-de-dados

O que vem a ser thread safe, e qual sua conexão com coleções de dados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você deve saber, se mais de um *thread* acessar o mesmo objeto podem ocorrer problemas de concorrência (conflitos/inconsistência nos dados que esse objeto contém, isto é, no estado desse objeto).

Dizer que uma classe é *thread safe* significa dizer que um objeto dessa classe pode ser acessado por mais de um *thread* sem que esses conflitos ocorram.

Uma coleção *thread safe* possui métodos para que você acesse ou itere (percorra) por seus dados sem que esses conflitos ocorram.

### Exemplos de situações em que é recorrente utilizar uma coleção *thread-safe*:

1. Em um chat para celular em que você mantém uma lista de mensagens, uma mensagem pode ser adicionada pelo usuário, o que geralmente ocorre no thread principal, ou pode chegar uma mensagem via rede de um outro usuário, o que costuma ocorrer em um thread secundário que fica aguardando a chegada de mensagens. Como é a mesma lista, a inserção de mensagens deve ser feita de maneira *thread-safe*.
2. Um outro exemplo semelhante, e também para celular, é um aplicativo de rastreamento que mantém uma lista de posições capturadas pelo GPS e tenta periodicamente enviá-las a um servidor. A lista pode tanto guardar objetos novos (posições que o GPS obtém dos satélites de geoposicionamento) como remover objetos (posições que já foram enviadas para o servidor).
3. Não diretamente relacionado a uma coleção, mas parecido: o banco de dados do Android é o SQLite, que não é *thread-safe*. Se você tiver mais de um thread querendo acessá-lo de maneira concorrente, terá que manter um monitor/lock para evitar que ocorra uma exceção caso o banco seja acessado pelos dois ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Você tem algum exemplo prático disso, ou alguma situação em que é recorrente utilizar uma coleção com thread safe?

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta com alguns exemplos.